# $X$ is a Geometric random variable find the expectation of $1/X$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X$ be a geometric random variable with parameter $p$, find the expectation of $E[1/X]$.

I need help simplifying the series.

Comment: Please show us your work

Comment: Where is your series?

Comment: its a geometric series.... its an expectation formula. I am sorry, but I am unfarmilar with the formating of this site. 

The series is sigma, index k from 1 to infinity, and the following series (1/k)p (1-p)^k-1   I know I am going to get scolded about not knowing the proper notation on math exchange but I have a final tomorrow . Also, I know there is a general formula but that will not suffice, I will have to know how to derive it. the answer comes out to be -p/(1-p)log(p) I believe according to my professor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to find the value of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty {p(1-p)^{k-1}\over k}$. Towards this end, let's find a formula for the sum of the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty {a^{k-1}\over k}={1\over a}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty {a^k\over k}$ when $0<a<1$. Note that this series indeed converges since it's dominated by a convergent geometric series.

But how to find its sum?

A hint here is to apply the Integration Theorem for power series to an appropriate series (that is a series that produces the series under scrutiny after integrating term by term).

I'll attempt to do this without making any errors:

Let's consider the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty {a^{k-1} }$. We will think of this series as a power series in the variable $a$. For a fixed $a\in(0,1)$, term by term integration of this series gives
$$\tag{1}
\int_0^a\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty {t^{k-1} } \,dt
=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \int_0^a {t^{k-1} } \,dt
=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty   {a^{k } \over k}.
$$

But, for $0<t\le a$,  $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty {t^{k-1} }={1\over 1-t} $; so the integral on the left hand side of $(1)$ is
$$
\int_0^a {1\over 1-t}\,dt=-\ln(1-a).
$$

We now have
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty {a^{k-1}\over k}
={1\over a}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty {a^{k}\over k}={-\ln(1-a)\over a};
$$
and so, with $ a=1-p<1$:
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty {p(1-p)^{k-1}\over k}={-p\ln p\over 1-p}.
$$

Comment: Thank you this clarified everything!

Comment: @OliviaIrving You're welcome.

Comment: If $X$ takes values from $1$ to $\infty$, then the possible values $1/X$ can take are $1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4,....$. So the summation for expected value $E(1/X)$ is not defined for values  $1$ to $\infty$; rather for $1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4,....$. I think the question itself is wrong. Am I correct here or is there any assumption made for solving this?

Comment: @AnkitSeth The "values" in the summation *are* $1, 1/2, 1/3, \dots$.  Recall the Law of the unconscious statistician.