# The expected value of $1/(1+X)$ where $X$ has geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

> Let $X$ be a random variable with a geometric distribution with parameter $p$.
>
> Calculate $\Bbb E[1/(1+X)]$

I've looked at answers online but still do not understand how to solve this.

Specifically, I do not understand how to to get from $$\frac{p}{1-p} \sum_{x=0}^\infty (1/(1+x))((1-p)^x+1)$$  to  $-p\ln(p)  /(1-p)$.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: How to to get from (p/(1-p))*Sigma(1/(1+x))((1-p)^x+1) with top sigma infinity and bottom x=0, to equal (-p(ln(p)))/(1-p). Judging by all the down votes I'm guessing this was definitely not the right math board for a beginner.

Comment: No, don't find $E(Y) = \sum_{y\in \{1, 1/2, 1/3, \ldots\}} y P(Y=y)$, find $E(1/(1+X)) = \sum_{x\in \{0, 1, 2\ldots\}} \frac 1{1+x} P(X=x)$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/257997/321264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $X\in \{0, 1, \ldots\}$ is the geometric distribution counting failures *before* a first success.

Use the fact that $\mathsf E(g(X)) = \sum_x g(x)\;\mathsf P(X=x)$

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X=x) & = p (1-p)^x \quad \mathbf 1_{x\in \{0, 1,2,\ldots\}}
\\[2ex]
\mathsf E\left(\frac 1{1+X}\right) & = \sum_{x=0}^\infty \; \frac 1{1+x} p(1-p)^x
\\[1ex] & = \frac{p}{1-p} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(1-p)^k}{k}
\end{align}$$

Then use the Taylor expansion: $$\ln (1+z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty {(-1)}^{k-1}\frac{z^k}{k}$$