# Conditional distribution similar to geometric random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The problem is :

> Consider independent trials, each of which results in outcome $0$, with probability $p$, and a non-zero outcome with value, with probability $1-p$. Let $N$ represent the number of trials needed to obtain a number that is not equal to $0$, and let $X=1/N$ be that outcome.
>
> (a) Show that $E[X]=(-p \ln p)/(1-p).$
>
> (b) What is probability $P(N\leq n | X \geq x)$?

I found $P(N=n)=p^{n-1}(1-p)$.
But how to get $E[X]$? 
I only have $E[X]=(1-p)+\frac{1}{2}p(1-p)+\frac{1}{3}p^2(1-p)+\cdots $, but I can't solve this like geometric random variables. And what is probability $P(N\leq n,X \geq x)$?

Comment: Hint: use the formula $\ln(1-x) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$ valid for $|x| < 1$.

Comment: For the expectation, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1197801/321264.

Comment: Note that $\ X\ge x\Leftrightarrow N\le\frac{1}{x}\ $.