# Bounding fractional moments of geometric random variable

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds, polylogarithm, geometric-distribution

The following two bounds for a fractional moment of a geometric random variable $X$ with $\mathbb{P}\left[X = k\right] = p \left(1 - p\right)^k$ where $k \geq 0$ are given in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4010) (on page 12):

Let $s \in \left(0, 1\right)$, then

- $\mathbb{E}\left[ X^s \right] \leq C_1\left(s\right) p^{-s} \left(1 - p\right)$, and
- $\mathbb{E}\left[ X^{-s} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{X > 0\right\}} \right] \leq C_2\left(s\right) p^s \left(1 - p\right)$

where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants depending only on $s$ (these inequalities can be expressed in terms of the polylogarithm, see below).

I would appreciate any **help in showing that the 2nd bound is true**. I do know how to prove the first bound, but the same method fails for the 2nd. You can show the first one by noting that $f\left(s\right) = \mathbb{E}\left[ \left(p X\right)^s \right]$ is convex and continuous in $s$, and can be continued to the interval $s \in \left[0, 1\right]$ with $f\left(0\right) = f\left(1\right) = 1-p$. By convexity, $f\left(s\right) \leq 1 - p$ for all $s \in \left(0, 1\right)$, which proves the bound with $C_1\left(s\right) = 1$.

Trying the same method on the 2nd bound yields the convex and continuous function $g\left(s\right) = \mathbb{E}\left[ \left(pX\right)^{-s} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{X > 0\right\}} \right]$ with $g\left(0\right) = 1-p$, but $g\left(1\right) = - \ln\left(p\right)$ (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257997/x-is-a-geometric-random-variable-find-the-expectation-of-1-x)), so we cannot get a constant $C_2$ which is independent of $p$ in this way.

Note that $\mathbb{E}\left[ X^s \right] = \sum_{k \geq 0} k^s p\left(1-p\right)^k = p \cdot \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{\left(1-p\right)^k}{k^{-s}} = p \cdot \textrm{Li}_{-s}\left(1-p\right)$ where $\textrm{Li}$ denotes the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), and $\mathbb{E}\left[ X^{-s} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{X > 0\right\}} \right] = p \cdot \textrm{Li}_{s}\left(1-p\right)$. So useful references on the behavior of the polylogarithm would also be appreciated.

Looking at [plots on WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%28x%29%5E%281%2F2%29+%2F+%281-x%29+*+PolyLog%5B1%2F2%2C+1-x%5D+for+x+from+0+to+1) (I plotted $\frac{p^{1-s}}{1-p} \textrm{Li}_{s}\left(1-p\right)$, which should be smaller than $C_2\left(s\right)$) shows that the critical region for the bound to be true is $p \to 0$, and indeed [calculating the limit on WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit%20for%20x%20to%200%20of%20%28x%29%5E%281%2F2%29%20%2F%20%281-x%29%20*%20PolyLog%5B1%2F2%2C%201-x%5D) confirms that such a constant $C_2\left(s\right)$ should exist, and also that the behavior of the polylogarithm seems to be better understood than what I could get from my internet researches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of showing the second bound is the following:

Let $Y \sim \textrm{Geo}(p)$ be a random variable with geometric distribution of parameter $p$, but which takes values in $\mathbb{N} \setminus \left\{0\right\}$, so $\mathbb{P}\left[Y = k\right] = q^{k-1} p$ where $k \geq 1$ and $q = 1 - p$. Then we can write
\begin{align}
    \label{eq:scnd_sum_bound}
    q \cdot \mathbb{E}\left[Y^{-s}\right] = q \cdot \sum_{k \geq 1} k^{-s} q^{k - 1} p = \sum_{k \geq 1} k^{-s} q^k p = \mathbb{E}\left[X^{-s} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{X > 0 \right\}} \right] &\leq C_2\left(s\right) qp^s \\
    \iff \mathbb{E}\left[\left(pY\right)^{-s}\right] &\leq C_2\left(s\right)
  \end{align}
Now, $g\left(p\right) = \mathbb{E}\left[\left(pY\right)^{-s}\right]$ is decreasing in $p$ (to see this, note that
$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(pY\right)^{-s}\right] = \frac{p^{1 - s}}{1 - p} \cdot \textrm{Li}_s\left(1 - p\right)$, derive: [https://bit.ly/3BOmLjP](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=d%2Fdx%20of%20x%5E%281-s%29%20%2F%20%281-x%29%20*%20PolyLog%5Bs%2C%201-x%5D),
and analyze the derivative: [https://bit.ly/3RVn5CA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20%28s%20*%20%28x%20-%201%29%20%2B%201%29%20*%20PolyLog%5Bs%2C%201-x%5D%20-%20x%20*%20PolyLog%5Bs%20-%201%2C%201-x%5D%20for%20x%20from%200%20to%201%20and%20s%20from%200%20to%201)), so it is sufficient to show that
$\lim_{p \to 0} g\left(p\right) =: C_2\left(s\right)$ exists and is finite. Note that for $p \to 0$,
$pY$ converges in distribution to a random variable $Z$ which is $\textrm{Exp}\left(1\right)$-distributed
(we have that $\mathbb{P}\left[pY > t\right] \to e^{-t}$ for $p \to 0$). Therefore, $\lim_{p \to 0} g\left(p\right) = \mathbb{E}\left[Z^{-s}\right] = \Gamma\left(1 - s\right) < \infty$
for $s \in \left(0, 1\right)$. Thus, we can choose $C_2\left(s\right) = \Gamma\left(1 - s\right)$.